# Python .app executable not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller, .app

I made a GUI program with Tkinter, and the .py version works fine but when I make a .app file with pyinstaller, the file won't open and I get the following errors in the console.

[image]

The same happens when I use py2app. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: try this it worked for me, I copied the `tcl` folder from python folder to folder which contained my `.py` file.

Comment: @shivsn in what directory path is the tcl folder exactly?

Comment: python installation directory like `C:\Python27`.